# Limit the rectangle to be drawn only once using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to draw the rectangle using the mouse down event only when the button is clicked. I have added the javascript code for a button event but its not working as it start drawing when the checkbox is clicked but keeps drawing even if the check box is unchecked. I want this to draw only when the button is checked. can I limit the rectangle to be drawn only once.

My fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/G6tLn/7/

I am modifying the simonsaris code for the selection handles using the mouse events.

Please help.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Canvas Demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
hr{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
form, table {display:inline; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.ck-button {
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#8080FF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
}
.ck-button:hover {
    background-color:#B2B2FF;
}
.ck-button label {
    float:left;
    width:4.0em;
}
.ck-button label span {
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px 0px;
    display:block;
}
.ck-button label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}
.ck-button input:checked + span {
    background-color:#0000FF;
    color:white;
}
   #container2 {
        position: relative;
    }

    #canvas2 {
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas2"
  width="450"
  height="450"
  style="border:2px solid black">

Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<div class="ck-button">
    <input type="checkbox" id="btnROI" value="ROI" onclick="CallRoi()">
    <span>ROI</span>


  <input type="checkbox" id="btnMetric" value="Metric" onclick="CallMetric()">
    <span>Metric</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // holds all our boxes
    var boxes2 = [];

    // New, holds the 8 tiny boxes that will be our selection handles
    // the selection handles will be in this order:
    // 0  1  2
    // 3     4
    // 5  6  7
    var selectionHandles = [];

    // Hold canvas information
    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    var WIDTH;
    var HEIGHT;
    var INTERVAL = 20;  // how often, in milliseconds, we check to see if a redraw is needed

    var isDrag = false;
    var isResizeDrag = false;
    var isCreationDrag = false;
    var expectResize = -1; // New, will save the # of the selection handle if the mouse is over one.
    var mx, my, startMx, startMy; // mouse coordinates

    // when set to true, the canvas will redraw everything
    // invalidate() just sets this to false right now
    // we want to call invalidate() whenever we make a change
    var canvasValid = false;

    // The node (if any) being selected.
    // If in the future we want to select multiple objects, this will get turned into an array
    var mySel = null;

    // The selection color and width. Right now we have a red selection with a small width
    var mySelColor = '#CC0000';
    var mySelWidth = 2;
    var mySelBoxColor = 'darkred'; // New for selection boxes
    var mySelBoxSize = 6;

    // we use a fake canvas to draw individual shapes for selection testing
    var ghostcanvas;
    var gctx; // fake canvas context

    // since we can drag from anywhere in a node
    // instead of just its x/y corner, we need to save
    // the offset of the mouse when we start dragging.
    var offsetx, offsety;

    // Padding and border style widths for mouse offsets
    var stylePaddingLeft, stylePaddingTop, styleBorderLeft, styleBorderTop;


    // Box object to hold data
    function Box2() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.w = 1; // default width and height?
        this.h = 1;
        this.fill = '#444444';
    }

    // New methods on the Box class
    Box2.prototype = {
        // we used to have a solo draw function
        // but now each box is responsible for its own drawing
        // mainDraw() will call this with the normal canvas
        // myDown will call this with the ghost canvas with 'black'
        draw:function (context, optionalColor) {
            if (context === gctx) {
                context.fillStyle = 'black'; // always want black for the ghost canvas
            } else {
                context.fillStyle = this.fill;
            }

            // We can skip the drawing of elements that have moved off the screen:
            if (this.x > WIDTH || this.y > HEIGHT) return;
            if (this.x + this.w < 0 || this.y + this.h < 0) return;

            context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);

            // draw selection
            // this is a stroke along the box and also 8 new selection handles
            if (mySel === this) {
                context.strokeStyle = mySelColor;
                context.lineWidth = mySelWidth;
                context.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);

                // draw the boxes

                var half = mySelBoxSize / 2;

                // 0  1  2
                // 3     4
                // 5  6  7

                // top left, middle, right
                selectionHandles[0].x = this.x - half;
                selectionHandles[0].y = this.y - half;

                selectionHandles[1].x = this.x + this.w / 2 - half;
                selectionHandles[1].y = this.y - half;

                selectionHandles[2].x = this.x + this.w - half;
                selectionHandles[2].y = this.y - half;

                //middle left
                selectionHandles[3].x = this.x - half;
                selectionHandles[3].y = this.y + this.h / 2 - half;

                //middle right
                selectionHandles[4].x = this.x + this.w - half;
                selectionHandles[4].y = this.y + this.h / 2 - half;

                //bottom left, middle, right
                selectionHandles[6].x = this.x + this.w / 2 - half;
                selectionHandles[6].y = this.y + this.h - half;

                selectionHandles[5].x = this.x - half;
                selectionHandles[5].y = this.y + this.h - half;

                selectionHandles[7].x = this.x + this.w - half;
                selectionHandles[7].y = this.y + this.h - half;


                context.fillStyle = mySelBoxColor;
                for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    var cur = selectionHandles[i];
                    context.fillRect(cur.x, cur.y, mySelBoxSize, mySelBoxSize);
                }
            }

        } // end draw

    }

    //Initialize a new Box, add it, and invalidate the canvas
    function addRect(x, y, w, h, fill) {
        var rect = new Box2;
        rect.x = x;
        rect.y = y;
        rect.w = w
        rect.h = h;
        rect.fill = fill;
        boxes2.push(rect);
        invalidate();
    }
function CallRoi(){

    var oROI = document.getElementById("btnROI");
    console.log(oROI.checked);

    if (oROI.checked) {
        init2();

    }
}
 function CallMetric(){

    var oMetric = document.getElementById("btnMetric");
    console.log(btnMetric.checked);

    if (oMetric.checked) {
        init1();
        console.log("hello");
    }
}    

    // initialize our canvas, add a ghost canvas, set draw loop
    // then add everything we want to intially exist on the canvas
    function init2() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
        HEIGHT = canvas.height;
        WIDTH = canvas.width;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ghostcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        ghostcanvas.height = HEIGHT;
        ghostcanvas.width = WIDTH;
        gctx = ghostcanvas.getContext('2d');

        //fixes a problem where double clicking causes text to get selected on the canvas
        canvas.onselectstart = function () {
            return false;
        }

        // fixes mouse co-ordinate problems when there's a border or padding
        // see getMouse for more detail
        if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
            stylePaddingLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingLeft'], 10) || 0;
            stylePaddingTop = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingTop'], 10) || 0;
            styleBorderLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderLeftWidth'], 10) || 0;
            styleBorderTop = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderTopWidth'], 10) || 0;
        }

        // make mainDraw() fire every INTERVAL milliseconds
        setInterval(mainDraw, INTERVAL);

        // set our events. Up and down are for dragging,
        // double click is for making new boxes
        canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
        canvas.onmouseup = myUp;
         canvas.ondblclick = myDblClick;
        canvas.onmousemove = myMove;


        // set up the selection handle boxes
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            var rect = new Box2;
            selectionHandles.push(rect);
        }

    }

    function init1() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
  HEIGHT = canvas.height;
  WIDTH = canvas.width;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ghostcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  ghostcanvas.height = HEIGHT;
  ghostcanvas.width = WIDTH;
  gctx = ghostcanvas.getContext('2d');

  //fixes a problem where double clicking causes text to get selected on the canvas
  canvas.onselectstart = function () { return false; }

  // fixes mouse co-ordinate problems when there's a border or padding
  // see getMouse for more detail
  if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    stylePaddingLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingLeft'], 10)     || 0;
    stylePaddingTop  = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingTop'], 10)      || 0;
    styleBorderLeft  = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderLeftWidth'], 10) || 0;
    styleBorderTop   = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderTopWidth'], 10)  || 0;
  }

  // make mainDraw() fire every INTERVAL milliseconds
  setInterval(mainDraw, INTERVAL);

  // set our events. Up and down are for dragging,
  // double click is for making new boxes
  canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
  canvas.onmouseup = myUp;
  canvas.ondblclick = myDblClick;
  canvas.onmousemove = myMove;

  // set up the selection handle boxes
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i ++) {
    var rect = new Box2;
    selectionHandles.push(rect);
  }

  // add custom initialization here:


  // add a large green rectangle
  addRect(50,180,50,50, 'green');

}


    //wipes the canvas context
    function clear(c) {
        c.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    // Main draw loop.
    // While draw is called as often as the INTERVAL variable demands,
    // It only ever does something if the canvas gets invalidated by our code
    function mainDraw() {
        if (canvasValid == false) {
            clear(ctx);

            // Add stuff you want drawn in the background all the time here

            // draw all boxes
            var l = boxes2.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                boxes2[i].draw(ctx); // we used to call drawshape, but now each box draws itself
            }

            // Add stuff you want drawn on top all the time here

            canvasValid = true;
        }
    }

    // Happens when the mouse is moving inside the canvas
    function myMove(e) {
        if (isDrag) {
            getMouse(e);

            mySel.x = mx - offsetx;
            mySel.y = my - offsety;

            // something is changing position so we better invalidate the canvas!
            invalidate();
        } else if (isResizeDrag) {
            // time ro resize!
            var oldx = mySel.x;
            var oldy = mySel.y;

            // 0  1  2
            // 3     4
            // 5  6  7
            switch (expectResize) {
                case 0:
                    mySel.x = mx;
                    mySel.y = my;
                    mySel.w += oldx - mx;
                    mySel.h += oldy - my;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mySel.y = my;
                    mySel.h += oldy - my;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mySel.y = my;
                    mySel.w = mx - oldx;
                    mySel.h += oldy - my;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mySel.x = mx;
                    mySel.w += oldx - mx;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    mySel.w = mx - oldx;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    mySel.x = mx;
                    mySel.w += oldx - mx;
                    mySel.h = my - oldy;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    mySel.h = my - oldy;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    mySel.w = mx - oldx;
                    mySel.h = my - oldy;
                    break;
            }

            invalidate();
        }

        getMouse(e);
        // if there's a selection see if we grabbed one of the selection handles
        if (mySel !== null && !isResizeDrag) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                // 0  1  2
                // 3     4
                // 5  6  7

                var cur = selectionHandles[i];

                // we dont need to use the ghost context because
                // selection handles will always be rectangles
                if (mx >= cur.x && mx <= cur.x + mySelBoxSize &&
                        my >= cur.y && my <= cur.y + mySelBoxSize) {
                    // we found one!
                    expectResize = i;
                    invalidate();

                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            this.style.cursor = 'nw-resize';
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            this.style.cursor = 'n-resize';
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            this.style.cursor = 'ne-resize';
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            this.style.cursor = 'w-resize';
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            this.style.cursor = 'e-resize';
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            this.style.cursor = 'sw-resize';
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            this.style.cursor = 's-resize';
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            this.style.cursor = 'se-resize';
                            break;
                    }
                    return;
                }

            }
            // not over a selection box, return to normal
            isResizeDrag = false;
            expectResize = -1;
            this.style.cursor = 'auto';
        }

    }

    // Happens when the mouse is clicked in the canvas
    function myDown(e) {

if (document.getElementById('btnROI').checked === false) return;
        getMouse(e);

        //we are over a selection box
        if (expectResize !== -1) {
            isResizeDrag = true;
            return;
        }

        clear(gctx);
        var l = boxes2.length;
        for (var i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // draw shape onto ghost context
            boxes2[i].draw(gctx, 'black');

            // get image data at the mouse x,y pixel
            var imageData = gctx.getImageData(mx, my, 1, 1);
            var index = (mx + my * imageData.width) * 4;

            // if the mouse pixel exists, select and break
            if (imageData.data[3] > 0) {
                mySel = boxes2[i];
                offsetx = mx - mySel.x;
                offsety = my - mySel.y;
                mySel.x = mx - offsetx;
                mySel.y = my - offsety;
                isDrag = true;

                invalidate();
                clear(gctx);
                return;
            }

        }
        // havent returned means we have selected nothing
//        mySel = null;

        addRect(mx, my, 0, 0, 'rgba(220,205,65,0.7)');
        mySel = boxes2[boxes2.length - 1];
//        console.log("box", box);
        offsetx = mx - mySel.x;
        offsety = my - mySel.y;
        mySel.x = mx - offsetx;
        mySel.y = my - offsety;
        isResizeDrag = true;
        expectResize = 7;

//        getMouse(e);
//        startMx = mx;
//        startMy = my;
        // clear the ghost canvas for next time
        // clear(gctx);
        // invalidate because we might need the selection border to disappear
        // invalidate();
    }


    function myUp(e) {
        isDrag = false;
        isResizeDrag = false;
        expectResize = -1;
        if (isCreationDrag) {
            // alert("end creation drag");
            getMouse(e);
            isCreationDrag = false;
            addRect(startMx, startMy, mx - startMx, my - startMy, 'rgba(220,205,65,0.7)');
        }
    }

    // adds a new node
    function myDblClick(e) {
        getMouse(e);
        // for this method width and height determine the starting X and Y, too.
        // so I left them as vars in case someone wanted to make them args for something and copy this code
        var width = 50;
        var height = 50;
        addRect(mx - (width / 2), my - (height / 2), width, height, 'green');
    }


    function invalidate() {
        canvasValid = false;
    }

    // Sets mx,my to the mouse position relative to the canvas
    // unfortunately this can be tricky, we have to worry about padding and borders
    function getMouse(e) {
        var element = canvas, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0;

        if (element.offsetParent) {
            do {
                offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
                offsetY += element.offsetTop;
            } while ((element = element.offsetParent));
        }

        // Add padding and border style widths to offset
        offsetX += stylePaddingLeft;
        offsetY += stylePaddingTop;

        offsetX += styleBorderLeft;
        offsetY += styleBorderTop;

        mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
        my = e.pageY - offsetY
    }



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line

```
if(!$("#btnROI").is(":checked") || boxes2.length > 0) return;
```

at the beginning of the myDown function (line 336 of the fiddle) to allow only one box to be drawn, and only when ROI is checked.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G6tLn/21

Comment: Hi @IrkenInvader , That's not working. If I am adding it to the starting of mouse down I am not able to draw anything.

Comment: Isn't that what we want? To allow drawing only when RMA is checked?

Comment: @Irkenlnvader Yes we want to draw only one yellow box which is happening when we click ROI but by adding this, I am not able to draw anything at all. and using boxes2.length > 0) I cannot draw the Metric box too

Comment: gives an error that ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Sounds like you are not using jQuery, my bad. This should make the $ not defined error go away: `if(document.getElementById('btnROI').checked === false || boxes2.length > 0) return;` I don't think i'm understanding the problem fully, only having the fiddle to work with.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Irkenlnvader , it does solve the problem of drawing only when the button is checked but creates another :(
it wont let me select any object and drag/resize which my basic criteria is.

Comment: I have added my whole code above which I am working on.

Comment: If we move the line a little further down we can still resize and drag the first box we create.  Try adding it just before `addRect(mx, my, 0, 0, 'rgba(220,205,65,0.7)');`

Comment: @Irkenlnvader Can we limit the no of ROI to be drawn only once ?? but allow other Metric and double click to work like before

Comment: I added a property to boxes2 in order to distinguish ROI boxes from other types of boxes.  This should only allow one box to be drawn while ROI is checked.  Line 383 forces either ROI or metric to be checked in order to draw a box, you can take that line out if that isn't what you want.  This code works best when only one checkbox is checked at a time, you might want to add some code to ensure that is the case.  Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G6tLn/21/